# Не могу запустить python файл через cmd

Tags: python, virtualenv, venv

Не могу понять, почему невозможно запустить файл. Виртуальное окружение активировал, но модуль почему-то он не видит. В IDE код запускается, а через обычное cmd не может. Скорее всего я чего-то не понимаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Брат, попробуй установить другую версию модуля, не уверен что поможет, но напиши в cmd это:

```
pip install vidstream==0.0.14
```